# Issue with Teradata PT load connection in Decimal Fields

Tags: teradata, informatica-powercenter

Earlier I was using odbc connection to execute a session in informatica.
Now we are trying to use TPT load connection in Target. using which performance has improved significantly compared to relational connection but we are facing mismatch issues in Decimal fields after processing the data using TPT connection.
Eg: with odbc we were getting 151.16
Using TPT its coming as    151.15

Can anyone please help!!
.
.

Comment: What are the source/target data types and precision? Perhaps something else in the mapping may have changed, e.g. one of the flows was converting to FLOAT and back (which can lose precision) or an inexact calculation that was previously done in the database is now being done in the client, etc.

Comment: Target data type is Decimal and precision is (15,3)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There's a checkbox in session properties 'Enable high precision'. That resolved the same issue for me.